# SQL Table Edited in MS Access - Deleting Field Data Creating Nulls, Need Blanks

Tags: t-sql, ms-access

We have a table in SQL server that one of our guys links to through ODBC in MS Access. He does this so he can update the table throughout the day in ways that quite honestly are not user-friendly in SQL server (fixing spelling in one field, adding notes to specific rows, etc.)

We do not want any NULLs in this table, and I have created constraints on those fields, but whenever he deletes the information in a specific field, it leaves a blank even though the constraint has a default value of N'' or 0 for nvarchar or int fields respectively.

I tried not allowing NULLs along with the default value constraint, but then it won't let him update any record where he deletes the information out of a field.

What is the best approach (with the tools being used as they are) to allow my guy to delete information out of a field, and not have to add a space just so it is not NULL, without the SQL table reading that field as a NULL?

Comment: I suppose you could run a procedure to replace Nulls with Blanks after he does his edits.  I assume his updates are free form & not controlled by forms, etc? If his access to the data is controlled by forms, you could put the procedure there for any field he updates - but if he's like me, that won't help much.

Comment: What database are you referring to with "in SQL"? I can't tell from your keywords. SQL Server? Oracle? MySQL? PostgreSQL? Please note SQL is a declarative, special-purpose programming language owned by no single company or software. Even MS Access with the Jet/ACE engine uses SQL. Consider editing for clarification especially since you discuss data types and rules which differ among RDMSs.

Comment: Thank you, @Parfait. I clarified the question since it's a SQL server table.

Comment: So @DonGeorge, you're basically saying that there is no good way to handle this? I guess I'm better off running a procedure to update all NULLs to blanks everyday before I export this SQL Server table to the AS400 table I update from this table each evening.

Comment: @rlphilli - not saying that's the only answer - just one approach.  But if your friend has unrestricted access directly to the data, I'm not sure how much control you have

Comment: Thanks, @DonGeorge. It's not so much about control as much as easiest way for him to do his normal editing work and the deletes being blanks instead of NULLs. Thanks for your recommendation.

Comment: You likely better off to allow nulls and assume any empty  column is null. You can’t avoid nulls in the long run anyway. For example any master + child table query that is a “left” join for will return nulls for the child columns. Since you as a “general” approach when using SQL will encounter nulls all the time (even if you never allowed null values in columns), then you might as well adopt the standard that any empty text column is null.  And this setup should not prevent issues with moving the Data to oracle since oracle can treat nulls and ZLS strings as the same.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the data your co-worker deletes to save as blanks instead of nulls, consider having the Access form clear content instead of deleting content.

Specifically, in the MS Access form whose recordsource is the SQL Server table, put a 'Clear Content' Command button or a click/double-click event for each field on the form for your co-worker. Behind the trigger event of the macro or VBA have fields equal to a zero length string:

`Me.nameofcontrol = ""`

But advise your co-worker to NOT press delete or use backspace on the keyboard or from the ribbon. Doing so will render the value equal to Null. As assurance to comply to this rule, you can set up a BeforeUpdate warning when the control's value is set to null.

```
If IsNull(Me.nameofcontrol) Then
    MsgBox "Field cannot have a null value. Please clear content if you want to delete.", vbInformation
    Cancel = True
    Me!nameofcontrol.Undo
End If
```

BeforeUpdate is usually the trigger event for form field validation. It uses the Cancel integer argument (either True or -1; False or zero). Undo is the same as pressing ESC on keyboard, returning the old value of the form control.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. I really was not thinking about using a command button, but that will be easy enough to implement, and since there are really only 2 people who update this table, advising them on how to use this will be easy. I'll update once I get this implemented.